# Is it ok to send to token from frontend to backend?

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend

If I have an application in which a user can connect to facebook from the frontend, it is ok to send the access token to the backend?

If there are security risks, what are them?

Comment: Have you read the official [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is ok.
You only should verify your token on backend. Facebook has special endpoint for that - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checktoken

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, you can send the long lived access tokens to the server so that you don't have to ask the user to authenticate with Facebook every time.

The concern is to keep the database encrypted at rest in the server so that the tokens are not compromised. Also consider sending it only to servers with https so that the data is not sent in plaintext from client